# CombineLatest and take(1)

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two BehaviorSubjects `$A` and `$B` with default values. Both of them are getting updated with values at different times using `.next(value)`. Much later in the code I am trying to pull the values like so

```
 Observable.combineLatest($A, $B)
  .take(1)
  .map(([$a, $b]) => {
    return {
      // stuff
    }
  })
  .subscribe(fn)
```

The behavior I'm seeing is odd. I was expecting the Observable to wait for either subject to emit a value and then give me one emitted value that I could pass to the subscribe function. But it only emits values with `$B` emits a new value. It will take the new value from `$A` when `$B` emits, but it won't do the reverse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest

Answer (score 3):

The `combineLatest` operator emits when all source Observables emit at **least one item** and then on **every emission** from any source Observable.

So if you want eg. `$A` to emit even when `$B` hasn't emitted anything you can prepend each source with `startWith`. In the resulting array you can check which index is filled with a value and thus tell what was the source Observable.

```
const a = $A.pipe(startWith(undefined));
const b = $B.pipe(startWith(undefined));

Observable.combineLatest(a, b)
  ...
```

I guess you're doing this because you want to know which source Observable emitted first. You could achieve the same with using just `merge` chained with `take(1)` where instead of `startWith` you could map each value to something uniquely distinguishable.